# Make a custom function from event on click

Tags: jquery, function

regards,
I need to create a custom function to the next event, I will need future use in other similar situations.

**Fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gonzalo2683/0qo8yL4j/embedded/result/)**

For example a have:

```
$('a.trigger').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataTrigger = $(this).attr('data-trigger');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass( 'fa-plus-square fa-minus-square'); //Cambia el icono

    if ($('div[data-container="' + dataTrigger + '" ]').length) {
        var elem = $('[data-container="' + dataTrigger +'"]');
        elem.toggle();
    }
});
```

Transform the click event to:

```
var showTables = function (){
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataTrigger = $(this).attr('data-trigger');
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass( 'fa-plus-square fa-minus-square'); //Cambia el icono

    if ($('div[data-container="' + dataTrigger + '" ]').length) {
        var elem = $('[data-container="' + dataTrigger +'"]');
        elem.toggle();
    }
}
```

I need call something like this:

```
$('a.trigger').on('click', function (e) {
   showTables();
});
```

How can you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with calling the function like this is that you lose the context of `this` within the `showTables` function. You have two options. Firstly, you could pass it as a parameter:

```
$('a.trigger').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showTables(this);
});

var showTables = function (that) {
    // your code, changing references of 'this' to 'that'
}
```

Alternatively you can leave the `showTables` as it is now and give the function reference to the handler to maintain the scope:

```
$('a.trigger').on('click', showTables);
```

The latter is preferable where possible due to its' brevity.

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked with the first option you propose.

The second I could not understand how to use it, because the browser returns me undefined values assigned to (this) value.

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the existing function in your click, rather than creating a new one:

```
$('a.trigger').on('click', showTables);
```